# Swift If Statement Not Working with UILabel

Tags: ios, if-statement, swift, uilabel

My if statement is not displaying what I want it to. Can anyone help? I want to display some text in a UILabel that will be decided from weather the random number is below or above 50.

Here is the code. The IF Statement is at the end.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var pianoSound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("two_tone_nav", ofType: "mp3")!)
var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: pianoSound, error: nil)
    audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBOutlet weak var Number: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var BA50: UILabel!

@IBAction func Generate(sender: AnyObject) {

           audioPlayer.play()

    var Generate = Int(arc4random_uniform(100))
    Number.text = String(Generate)


    func AboveBelow50(){
        if Generate>=50 {
        self.BA50.text = "No"
    }
        else {
    self.BA50.text = "Yes"
    }

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your function:

```
func AboveBelow50(Generate: Int){
    if Generate>=50 {
        self.BA50.text = "No"
    }  else {
        self.BA50.text = "Yes"
    }
```

Out side your IBAction, and change it this way.

And call inside your IBAction:

```
   var Generate = Int(arc4random_uniform(100))
   AboveBelow50(Generate)
```